# Nested divs are not properly displaying

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a column that has two columns nested inside it. I would like to create a few of these in a row as well.

The image below shows what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

I have tried to code the following in the snippet, but it doesn't look like the image that I am trying to recreate.

I am not sure how to get this, since I thought it was going to be straight forward job.

Thanks.

```css
.matches {
  background: #999;
}
.club-back {
  height: 230px;
}
.team-data {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  height: 100%;
}
.team-data p {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
.team-data p:first-child {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.team-data p:last-child {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.team-data span {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="slider-three">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 matches">
          <div class="row">
            <p class="text-center">title</p>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="club-back">
                <div class="col-md-12 team-data">
                  <p>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/130x140" class="center-block" alt="image" />
                  </p>
                  <p>Title</p>
                  <p>sub-title</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="club-back">
                <div class="col-md-12 team-data">
                  <p>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/130x140" class="center-block" alt="image" />
                  </p>
                  <p>Title</p>
                  <p>Sub-title</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: if my answer works for you please accept and if you like it vote up.  ...I'm trying to gain some reputation here! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have not included the bootstrap.css library into your code. In below snippet I have added cdn. See the result in full screen.

```css
.matches {
  background: #999;
}
.club-back {
  height: 230px;
}
.team-data {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  height: 100%;
}
.team-data p {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
.team-data p:first-child {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.team-data p:last-child {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.team-data span {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.margin-bottom{margin-bottom:20px;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">

  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="slider-three">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 matches">
          <div class="row">
            <p class="text-center">title</p>
            <div class="col-md-6 margin-bottom">
              <div class="club-back">
                <div class="col-md-12 team-data">
                  <p>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/130x140" class="center-block" alt="image" />
                  </p>
                  <p>Title</p>
                  <p>sub-title</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 margin-bottom">
              <div class="club-back">
                <div class="col-md-12 team-data">
                  <p>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/130x140" class="center-block" alt="image" />
                  </p>
                  <p>Title</p>
                  <p>Sub-title</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: right, however, this hasnt fixed my issue at all...It is still not displaying how I would like it to look in my image...

Comment: @Krystyna, I have edited code, mark as answer if it worked for you

Comment: this is nearly close to what I am asking! Thankyou. However, in responsive view, the grey background should cover the back of each 'white' div, here the white background div's integrate together. Is there a way to keep the grey background in place, and keep each white div's seperated?

Comment: here is how I wish it to look like in responsive view in response to my last comment: http://i.imgur.com/aDWtHCK.jpg

Comment: @Krystyna, Updated

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```css
#container{
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
  background:grey;
}
#header{
  width:100%;

  text-align:center;
  margin-top:32px;
}
.column{
  margin-left:2%;
  margin-right:2%;
  width:46%;
  float:left;
  height:200px;
  background: white;

}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">header</div>
  <div class="column">asdf</div>
  <div class="column">asdf</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Roy Royston thanks, but this is not for the entire page. Its suppose to be grey divs next to each other on the same line...

Comment: my result looks identical to what you asked for.  If you want the 'asdf' text centered simply add `text-align:center` to the columns class.  My solution does not have to be full page - it can be a child portion of a page.

Comment: is there a way I can do without the specific 'container' div? I already have a div for the main page...It has to be columns like 'col-md-2' not manually setted css widths..

Comment: Use the div you already have for the main page, or even use `body` or `main` or `section` elements.  Simply mode the `id=container` to the outer div you want to.  Flexbox is another way to do what you want but is relatively new with some potential cross browser support issues that may be worked around with a polyfill.  see http://demo.agektmr.com/flexbox/

Comment: @Roy Royston. Thanks for your snippet version again, however, in your CSS you have manually set widths and margins -- this is what I wish to stay away from. Can't my problem be resolved with bootstrap columns alone? Why do I have to initiate set widths, if bootstrap columns already have these in place by default? Just trying to understand this...Also, I sincerely dislike the flexbox option for obvious reasons.

Comment: @Krystyna the only literal distances are the height ones.  Those are there becuase without content to fill the space, the box shrinks to fit, resulting in a demo that looks wrong.  Try setting the literal distances to relative (change from px to %) and add some content.  In other words change 'asdf' to 'Lorem Ipsum ... (use 100 words or more).  Also, have a look at min-height.  Try setting min-height.